# Как в консольном приложении разбирать параметры командной строки и выводить по ним справку

Tags: c#

Нужно написать консольное приложение на С#, чтобы при вводе команды `run -h` выводилась справка с описанием команд.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string command = string.Empty;
    if (args.Length != 0)
    {
        switch (args[0])
        {
            case "-h": help();
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void run(string utilityName, string arguments)
{
    try
    {
        clearOutput();
        pr = new Process();
        pr.StartInfo.FileName = utilityName;
        pr.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    }
    catch ()  {} // ошибки
}

public static help()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-h help");
}
```

Comment: Что было предпринято для решения задачи?
И да, в `main` вроде как передаётся массив аргументов, нет?

Comment: `switch (args[0])` - а если приложение будет запущено так: `run -ключ -ещё_ключ -h`?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, run - для создания процесса, -h - ключ (она же функция для вывода справки), а  filename - параметр. Например run -f filename - открыть файл с именем filename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вручную аргументы командной строки парсить не надо. То, что вы напишете, практически наверняка будет будет обладать ограниченным функционалом и зоопарком багов. Не надо изобретать велосипед.

Если вам нужна работа с аргументами в более удобной форме, чем предоставленной `string[] args` в `Main`, [`Environment.CommandLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.commandline) или [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs), то вы можете воспользоваться одним из многочисленных пакетов с парсерами командной строки на NuGet. Они вам позволят интерпретировать аргументы как имена и значения, преобразуют типы значений, сгенерируют справку и т. п.

Любой парсер, который вы найдёте, будет выдавать пары аргумент-значение. Есть различия в поддерживаемом синтаксисе, типах аргументов, API (декларативные, императивные, ни рыба ни мясо), но базовый функцонал у всех единый.

Большой популярностью пользуется [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/), но я бы предостерёг от его использования: старая адекватная версия библиотеки заброшена и страдает от нескольких багов, новая версия переписана в совершенно упоротом стиле, неподдерживаема, и светлого будущего не видать. Список популярных библиотек:

- [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) — самая популярная, самая упоротая
- [FluentCommandLineParser](https://github.com/fclp/fluent-command-line-parser) — другая популярная
- [PowerArgs](https://github.com/adamabdelhamed/PowerArgs) — ещё одна популярная
- [System.CommandLine](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/System.CommandLine) — <s>часть Core FX Lab от Microsoft, кандидат на включение в дотнет</s> перенесена в архив Core FX Lab от Microsoft
- [CommandLineUtils](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils) — изначально часть Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, сейчас поддерживается другим разрабом
- Всё, что вы [найдёте на NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=command+line)

Одни библиотеки ожидают от вас классов с атрибутами на свойствах, другие конфига, построенного с помощью fluent интерфейса, но в любом случае это будет сделать проще, чем изобрести велосипед, и вы получите более широкий функционал: генерацию справки, валидацию аргументов, строгую типизацию и т. п.

Comment: Я тоже в своё время писал. :) Мне кажется, такой велосипед стоит написать раз в жизни.

Comment: @VladD У меня были позывы, но я себя пересилил. Сказал себе, что буду писать парсер командной строки, только если основательно протестирую первые 20 самых популярных, и ни один меня не удовлетворит. На данный момент я знаю ограничения и баги CommandLineParser. Осталось 19. :) (Вообще я статью со сравнением готовил. Но число библиотек значительно превысило мои возможности даже сравнить *заявленные возможности*.)

Comment: Если речь идёт о коммерческом применении, то проще написать свой велосипед, чем пытаться разобраться в чужом коде, _если_ требуемый формат не поддерживается библиотекой из коробки :-\ Например, при беглом взгляде на `CommandLineParser` я не нашёл синтаксиса для `-addDir "C:\123" -addDir "D:\456" -addDir "E:\789"` -> `IEnumerable<string>`. (Зато у меня не поддерживается `Nullable`, добавлю.)

Comment: А мини-обзор был бы полезен, кстати. Если есть наброски, может, сделаете вопросоответ? (Если нет планов выложить на Хабр или куда-нибудь ещё.)

Comment: @VladD Там совсем наброски. Жалкая попытка классификации фич. На 15-й библиотеке я сдался.

Comment: Перетащил содержательную часть из ответа к дубликату. Народ почему-то решил проигнорировать полноту ответа при выборе основного вопроса.

Comment: `System.CommandLine` перенесли в архив: https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab#archived-projects, https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/pull/2245#issuecomment-386087638

Comment: @VladD Хм. Досадно. Это была простая библиотека, но мне её архитектура очень нравилась: она дизайнилась как фреймворковая основа с полноценным API, а не закрытая вундервафля.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, как только речь заходит о разборе параметров командной строки - первым делом нужно проверять есть ли для данной платформы/языка порт [GNU getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html). Для этого случая - [есть](http://getopt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

Если хочется подробностей и разобраться как это работает - [исходники очень хорошо откомментированы](http://getopt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Gnu.Getopt/Gnu.Getopt/Getopt.cs) (комментариев и пояснений там реально больше, чем самого кода, всё разложено по полочкам и разжёвано в кашу).

Comment: была идея парсить параметры string[] command = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); Потом их заносить в массив и для каждого потом прописывать действия

Comment: Ну, никто не может помешать вам тратить время на изобретение очередного велосипеда  :) Даже когда есть решение, проверенное десятилениями и миллионами запусков...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все таки хотелось бы разобраться в этой теме Вот еще один вариант парсинга аргументов http://habrahabr.ru/post/38896/

Comment: Так смотрите в исходники и разбирайтесь, там всё наглядно и с подробнейшими пояснениями. Или нужно обязательно медленно, без чужого накопленного опыта, набивая свои собственные шишки и доставая окружающих простейшими вопросами?

Comment: См. обновление ответа.

Answer (score 1):

На, почитай вот это: https://commandline.codeplex.com
Единственная проблема, я не владею C#, так что на вопросы очень слабо смогу поотвечать.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
...
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
List<string> list = new List<string>(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = "\"" + fi.FullName + "\" " + String.Join(" ", list.ToArray()).Trim();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]